# Always run .exe with certain priority

Tags: windows-7, priority

I have an executable, say `foo.exe`. Because of a bug I need this executable to run at "low" priority at all times. The executable gets opened by another executable so replacing it with a batch file is not possible (as far as I know).

The executable is part of a game, so replacing it with a starter executable might trigger some integrity checks.

What would be a working solution?

Comment: [This looks like it might work](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-permanently-set-process-priority-in-windows-task-manager/). I haven't tested it, though, and the comments indicate it may not work on Windows 7, which is why I am not posting this as an answer.